# What effects can hit a phasing creature in a nonmagical wall square?

Tags: dnd-4e, line-of-sight, line-of-effect, wall, phasing

In a recent battle I was Dming, the party was fighting against Wraiths (in the [Madness at Gardmore Abbey adventure](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/355930000)).  Wraiths have **phasing** and thus can fly into and through walls, so the players and I were all wondering if there are any effects that can hit a creature in a wall.

I believe that walls block **line-of-effect** and **line-of-sight**, but what does that mean for **auras** or other effects?

**Do any effects or attack types penetrate walls without specifically stating so?**

(I just realized you have to end your turn out of a wall, but some interrupts and effects could still take place while a creature was traveling through a wall)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need Line of Effect to "effect" creatures.**

This is true for [Aura's](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=344)

> The aura fills the creature’s space and each square that is both within a specified distance of the creature and within line of effect of it.

[Blasts](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=125)

> A blast affects a target only if the target is in the blast’s area and if there is line of effect from the origin square to the target.

[Bursts](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=126)

> A burst affects a target only if there is line of effect from the burst’s origin square to the target.

[Close Attacks](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=123)

> For a target to be affected by a close attack, there must be line of effect from the origin square to the target.

[Opportunity Attacks](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=331) require Line of Sight

> You can’t make an opportunity attack unless you are able to make a melee basic attack and you can see your enemy.

Comment: don't forget zones and other "adjacent to" effects like storm pillar and flaming sphere.

Comment: @Snowbody - zones are typically created by a blast/burst/close power and are limited thusly.

Answer (score 1):

Walls are blocking terrain<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=504)</sup> and block all effects, including zones, unless that effect specifically says it extends through walls.